# multiple lines in kubernetes cron job "schedule"

Tags: kubernetes, cron

Suppose I want a job to run every 10 minutes on workdays and every 3 hours on weekends.
Do I have to specify two separate jobs, one for workdays and another for weekends,
or I can write something like this?

```
schedule:> */10 *  * * 1-5
           *   */3 * * sat,sun
```

This is just a simple example; real-life examples may be trickier. Like, run stuff during the daytime, sleep at night, etc.